# How to retrieve specific value from cookie send by asp.net in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying single sign on cross browsing using cookies

So I get cookie from asp.net named "**logininfo**"

When I print values of cookie in php using

```
session_start();
$NAME=$_COOKIE['logininfo'];
echo $_COOKIE["logininfo"];
```

I get Result as

```
Emp_Id=119&Org_Id=11&Unit_Id=123&UserId=116
```

How can i fetch vlaue of Emp_Id, Org_Id and Unit_Id separately using php

Comment: asp or php pick one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

> (function available in PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> parse_str — Parses the string into variables

And then you can `echo` variable seperatly

```
parse_str($_COOKIE["logininfo"], $result);
echo "Employee id = ".$result['Emp_Id'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "Organization id = ".$result['Org_Id'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "Unit id = ".$result['Unit_Id'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "User id = ".$result['UserId'];
```

A sample Output:- https://eval.in/964766

Comment: @PoojaDhoot  glad to help you.:):)

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
parse_str($NAME, $result);
```

Then `$result` will hold the values as an associative array

```
array(4) {
   'Emp_Id' =>
   string(3) "119"
   'Org_Id' =>
   string(2) "11"
   'Unit_Id' =>
   string(3) "123"
   'UserId' =>
   string(3) "116"
}
```